# How to assign to char from const char *

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, type-conversion, char

I have the following C code

```
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]){

int counter = 1;
char input[1000000];

while(argv[counter] != NULL){
input[counter] = argv[counter]
}

return 0;
}
```

This gives the warning incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]

I can loop through and print out the values of argv[counter] so im confused why i can't set a variable equal to them.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The warning tells you exactly what is wrong. argv[] is an array of char *. argv[counter] is a char *. You can't assign a pointer to a char.

Comment: i want to set set each element of input equal to the corresponding element of argv. so for example if argv[2] = 5, i want input[2] to equal 5

Comment: argv[] is an array of strings. What do you want to do if argv[2] is "banana" ? argv[2] will almost certainly never have a value that can be stored in a char. It is a pointer.

Comment: Also, since your code doesn't actually do anything at all (i.e. doesn't display anything or interact with the world), an optimising compiler might replace all your code with literally nothing at all. Maybe if you had a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with what the inputs, outputs, and expected outputs are, people would better be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of const string while `input` is an array of character. So your first step is to make `input` array of string by doing this  `char *input[1000000]` and lastly you have to cast each `const string` of `argv` before assigning it to `input` by doing this  `input[counter] = (char *)argv[counter]`.

**Edit Suggested By @David Ranieri**

You can remove `const` from `argv` to avoid the casting.

**ALSO**

As @NoDakker said in the comment section. You have to increment `counter` to avoid infinite loop.

**Solution**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]){

int counter = 1;
char *input[1000000];

while(argv[counter] != NULL){
input[counter] = (char *)argv[counter];
counter++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if the counter variable is not incremented, that while loop will never be exited and will just be an endless loop.

Comment: @NoDakker sure thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't paying attention to that